# Jaxb @XmlAttribute

Tags: xml, jaxb

I have the following problem. I cannot read the attribute style of every line.
I have created a class that contains "linea" and "style" but not if it is the correct thing.

This is Xml to read.

```
<aviso id="20642227720571316020140523421272">
        <titulo>
                <linea style="12">Etiquetado</linea>
        </titulo>
        <informacion>
                <linea style="13">MONTAR CAJA TIPO: (3) - Caja grande</linea>
                <linea style="14">PEGAR MATRICULA: M142849863</linea>
        </informacion>
        <instrucciones>
                <linea style="15">EMISION DE ETIQUETA EN CURSO...</linea>
        </instrucciones>
</aviso>
```

This is generic Class java

```
public class TextosMensaje {

    private String linea;
    private String style;

    public TextosMensaje() {
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "linea")
    public String getLinea() {
        return linea;
    }

    public void setLinea(String linea) {
        this.linea = linea;
    }


    @XmlAttribute(name="style")
    public String getStyle() {
        return style;
    }

    public void setStyle(String style) {
        this.style = style;
    }

}
```

This is java Class where I believe the lists.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "aviso")
public class Aviso {

    private String id;

    private List<TextosMensaje> tituloList;
    private List<TextosMensaje> informacionList;
    private List<TextosMensaje> instruccionesList;

    public Aviso() {
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "titulo")
    @XmlElement(name = "linea")
    public List<TextosMensaje> getTituloList() {
        return tituloList;
    }

    public void setTituloList(List<TextosMensaje> tituloList) {
        this.tituloList = tituloList;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "informacion")
    @XmlElement(name = "linea")
    public List<TextosMensaje> getInformacionList() {
        return informacionList;
    }

    public void setInformacionList(List<TextosMensaje> informacionList) {
        this.informacionList = informacionList;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "instrucciones")
    @XmlElement(name = "linea")
    public List<TextosMensaje> getInstruccionesList() {
        return instruccionesList;
    }

    public void setInstruccionesList(List<TextosMensaje> instruccionesList) {
        this.instruccionesList = instruccionesList;
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your use case the `linea` element corresponds to a complex type with simple content.  As such you should annotate your class as follows leveraging the `@XmlValue` annotation on the `linea` property.

```java
public class TextosMensaje {

    private String linea;
    private String style;

    public TextosMensaje() {
    }

    @XmlValue
    public String getLinea() {
        return linea;
    }

    public void setLinea(String linea) {
        this.linea = linea;
    }


    @XmlAttribute
    public String getStyle() {
        return style;
    }

    public void setStyle(String style) {
        this.style = style;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about this use case on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html